# What is the relationship between embeddings and deep metric learning?

Tags: machine-learning, metric, embeddings

Embeddings and deep metric learning seem architecturally identical. They both rely on using some hidden layer's vector representation of an input.

What is the difference between the two? Are embeddings trained indirectly (as the side effect of a classification task), and deep metric learning embeddings trained independently with a specialized loss function?

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of the answer that I could find by myself.

Embeddings learned during normal classification (using cross-entropy loss) are separable, but not discriminative.

To make the embeddings discriminative, we can either learn the embeddings directly with a special loss function like contrastive / triplet / center loss, or add that loss function to cross-entropy during classification training.

Here's a diagram from [A Discriminative Feature Learning Approach for Deep Face Recognition](https://ydwen.github.io/papers/WenECCV16.pdf), where the embeddings in (a) are from heavily weighting cross-entropy loss, and (d) heavily weighting center loss.

[image]